# How to use Select in Substring when I need also select?

Tags: sql, vertica

Hello I am using `WITH A AS... , B as ....` commands. However, in C I needed to take first value from a column in  B table. Tried to use ```select(substr(select Table1 from B,0,1)
However I had an error. Can you help, how can I extract first value in the temporary tables?

I.E. data is

```
CREATE temp TABLE XXX (DATE TEXT, PRICE INTEGER);
INSERT INTO XXX VALUES 
('2019-04-27 01:00', 1), ('2019-04-27 02:30', 3), ('2019-04-27 18:00',2), 
('2019-04-28 17:00', 2), ('2019-04-28 21:00', 5), 
('2019-04-29 17:00',50), ('2019-04-29 21:00',10), 
('2019-04-30 17:00',10), ('2019-04-30 21:00',20), 
('2019-05-01 17:00',40), ('2019-05-01 21:00',10), 
('2019-05-02 17:00',10), ('2019-05-02 21:00', 6);
```

In A table I get 3 the most recents dates. In B column I calculated difference in days between A dates and Today. However data also includes hours/minutes. By using substring in Table C I wanted to avoid minutes/hours in Table B.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What do YOU mean by "first value from a column in a B table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added description. Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason the DATE column has a TEXT datatype rather than a date/datetime datatype?

Comment: @KMoe No, there is no reason. Was thinking it i a string, but if SQL has datatime type, so i should use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are making your first steps into a relational database - welcome to the fun!

I changed the script to hard-cast the `TRUNC()` expression to a DATE type explicitly.

Alternatively, you can also use the function `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` (Which is `DATEDIFF()` in SQL Server, for example).

We have - not only in Vertica, but also in all DBMSs, data types and functions for those data types that make your life much , much easier.

In the example below, I use the right type for a literal like `'2019-04-27 01:00'` - which is a timestamp without fractions of seconds - a `TIMESTAMP(0)` .

You can get the date part of a timestamp with the function `TRUNC(the_timestamp)` which I use below.

And in a  big number of RDBMS-s , you can subtract whole dates and get integers as difference - among which Vertica - which I do.

Selecting the 3 most recent dates is selecting the date, order by it descending, and limiting the result to 3 rows.

See what I do here below ...

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE xxx(dt, price) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-04-27 01:00', 1
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-04-27 02:30', 3
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-04-27 18:00', 2
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-04-28 17:00', 2
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-04-28 21:00', 5
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-04-29 17:00',50
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-04-29 21:00',10
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-04-30 17:00',10
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-04-30 21:00',20
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-05-01 17:00',40
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-05-01 21:00',10
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-05-02 17:00',10
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-05-02 21:00', 6
)
;

-- GET THE 3 MOST RECENT DATES ...
SELECT
  dt
FROM xxx ORDER BY dt DESC
LIMIT 3
;
-- out          dt          
-- out ---------------------
-- out  2019-05-02 21:00:00
-- out  2019-05-02 17:00:00
-- out  2019-05-01 21:00:00

-- CALCULATE DIFFERENCE IN DAYS BETWEEN THE DATE AND TODAY ..
SELECT
  *
, CURRENT_DATE - TRUNC(dt)::DATE AS daydiff_to_today
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,TRUNC(dt), CURRENT_DATE) AS daydiff_timestampdiff
FROM xxx
ORDER BY 1;
-- out          dt          | price | daydiff_to_today | daydiff_timestampdiff 
-- out ---------------------+-------+------------------+-----------------------
-- out  2019-04-27 01:00:00 |     1 |              366 |                   366
-- out  2019-04-27 02:30:00 |     3 |              366 |                   366
-- out  2019-04-27 18:00:00 |     2 |              366 |                   366
-- out  2019-04-28 17:00:00 |     2 |              365 |                   365
-- out  2019-04-28 21:00:00 |     5 |              365 |                   365
-- out  2019-04-29 17:00:00 |    50 |              364 |                   364
-- out  2019-04-29 21:00:00 |    10 |              364 |                   364
-- out  2019-04-30 17:00:00 |    10 |              363 |                   363
-- out  2019-04-30 21:00:00 |    20 |              363 |                   363
-- out  2019-05-01 17:00:00 |    40 |              362 |                   362
-- out  2019-05-01 21:00:00 |    10 |              362 |                   362
-- out  2019-05-02 17:00:00 |    10 |              361 |                   361
-- out  2019-05-02 21:00:00 |     6 |              361 |                   361
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I got daydiff variable as 364 00:00:00, but I need without hour/minute/seconds stamps. How can it be achieved?

Comment: cast the `TRUNC()` expression to date . I'll change my answer accordingly ...

Answer (score 1):

I converted the datatype from Text to string, only selected the 'yyyy-MM-dd' then converted data back into Text, ready to be inserted into table_c

It think it would be best practice to use a more appropriate datatype for your columns as it would make querying them so much easier and keep the data cleaner.

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(CAST(DATE AS nvarchar(18)),10) AS TEXT) AS [DATE], PRICE 
INTO TABLE_C
FROM XXX
```